Are oriented-$h$-cobordant lens spaces orientation-preservingly homeomorphic?
Consider two three-dimensional lens spaces $N_1=L(p,q_1)$ and $N_2=L(p,q_2)$, and assume that there is an oriented-$h$-cobordism between them. In other words, we assume that there is an oriented four-manifold $M$ such that $\partial M=(-N_1)\sqcup N_2$, where the boundary has the induced orientation, and we assume in addition that the inclusions $N_1\to M$ and $N_2\to M$ are homotopy equivalences. I saw here that this implies that they are homeomorphic. However, with the orientation assumptions, does this also imply that the homeomorphism can be taken to preserve orientation?

Yes, you can recover the extra orientation information from the Reidemeister torsion. Actually, a much stronger statement is true: homology cobordant 3D lens spaces are oriented homeomorphic.

@mme Do you perhaps happen to know of a good reference for this?

I deleted my answer, because it didn't ever point out the relevance of h-cobordisms! In fact, Reidemeister torsion is most clearly a simple homotopy invariant, and it is a priori possible that the h-cobordism relation is weaker. Sorry about this. However, there is a reference: the result is stated as Corollary 12.12 in Milnor, "Whitehead Torsion". The result is given in all dimensions. A reference for the claim about homology cobordism is here.

@mme I think the result in Milnor is not quite enough, since it requires the h-cobordism to preserve "preferred generators". However, the arXiv link is exactly what I needed!
